# Squeeze chart in the JQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, highcharts

I am developing a JQuery mobile application with an HighCharts chart displayed in the content area. I would like to squeeze the entire graph in the visible area of the phone, so no scrolling is necessary. I have tried the to change view port content

```
$.mobile.metaViewportContent = 'width=device-width, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1';
```

but id doesn't seem to do the trick. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The chart will be rendered to fill it's containing div, so you need to make sure the containing div is the correct size. Normally it would be sufficient to give the containing div a css with:

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Obviously it can be more complicated depending on the settings of any parent elements etc.